# What does モダンな時間 mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

大人のためのモダンな時間をあなたに……。バーテンも惡くないですな！

My version is - "A modern pastime for mature persons, that is what I offer you......"

Comment: "Modern" is **far** from what 「モダン」 means here.  That is just what bilingual dictionaries would tell you.  Try looking it up in a better monolingual dictionary.

Comment: OK, Yahoo told me it can also mean "fashionable". So it's "fashionable pastime" here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I don't know how semantically モダン shifted from English "Modern".

Probably they want to make stylish ambiance which is playing Jazz and have the customer enjoy the time.

Comment: +1 but I need to add a few words. 「モダンな」, in this context, has the combined meaning of "fashionable", "refined", "chic", etc.  and that is the kind of time the bartender strives to create/provide for you.  **Learners should really forget the word "modern" here**.  「モダンな」 certainly has that meaning as well, but not in this context as it would make no sense to say that the bartender wants you to have a modern time.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and taking time to read. But I assume it is not strange to bring artistic thing the word "modern" has. Anyway, it might interrupts.